# ggploting multiple columns in one bar graph which are grouped by a 4th column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that takes the format below (couldn't do it any better), with game sales from 3 regions grouped by gerne, i would like to ggplot them in a bar graph, where for example the Action genre would be in the x axis and 3 bars for the 3 regions are represented by their values in y axis , and so on.[sample desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJdxy.png)

```
Genre : Action,Sport,Fighting,Platform
NA : 10, 13, 3, 5
EU : 7, 11, 1, 3
JP : 8, 10, 2, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
  ~Region, ~Action, ~Sport, ~Fighting, ~Platform,
      NA,     10L,    13L,        3L,        5L,
    "EU",      7L,    11L,        1L,        3L,
    "JP",      8L,    10L,        2L,        9L
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Region) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = Region)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jon, you are awesome, i wanted to ask about giving these bars a border, but i found out how, thanks again :)